# If else operation for pages yii2

Tags: yii2

I have 3 pages that is similar, Page A, Page B, and Page C. All of these pages are to create new data.

How to do if else using pages?

The ideas is like this:

```
Page A ----> actionCreate() -----> render to 'create'
Page B ----> actionCreate() -----> render to 'create-obituary'
Page C ----> actionCreate() -----> render to 'create-anniversary'
```

Controller.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model = new Memoriam(['scenario'=>'create']);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //$model->owner_id = $session['UserID'];
        $model->picture1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'picture1');
        //$model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->validate()) {
                if($model->picture1 != null)
                {
                    $dir = "img/".$session['UserID']."/memoriam/";

                    if(!file_exists($dir)) 
                    {
                        $old = umask(0);
                        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                        umask($old);
                    }
                    $path = md5(date("YmdHis")) . '.' . $model->picture1->extension;
                    $model->picture1->saveAs($dir.$path);
                    $model->picture1 = $path;
                    $model->page = 1;
                }



            if($model->save(false)){
                return $this->redirect(['site/profile', 'id' => $model->ID]);
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreateDeparted()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model = new Memoriam(['scenario'=>'create']);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //$model->owner_id = $session['UserID'];
        $model->picture1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'picture1');
        //$model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->validate()) {
                if($model->picture1 != null)
                {
                    $dir = "img/".$session['UserID']."/memoriam/";

                    if(!file_exists($dir)) 
                    {
                        $old = umask(0);
                        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                        umask($old);
                    }
                    $path = md5(date("YmdHis")) . '.' . $model->picture1->extension;
                    $model->picture1->saveAs($dir.$path);
                    $model->picture1 = $path;
                    $model->page = 8;
                }



            if($model->save(false)){
                return $this->redirect(['site/profile', 'id' => $model->ID]);
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create-departed', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create-departed', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreateAnniversary()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model = new Memoriam(['scenario'=>'create']);
    $modelAnn = new Anniversary();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelAnn->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //$model->owner_id = $session['UserID'];
        $model->picture1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'picture1');
        //$model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->validate()) {
                if($model->picture1 != null)
                {
                    $dir = "img/".$session['UserID']."/memoriam/";

                    if(!file_exists($dir)) 
                    {
                        $old = umask(0);
                        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                        umask($old);
                    }
                    $path = md5(date("YmdHis")) . '.' . $model->picture1->extension;
                    $model->picture1->saveAs($dir.$path);
                    $model->picture1 = $path;

                }
            $model->page = 4;
            $model->save();
            $modelAnn->decease_id = $model->ID;
            $modelAnn->save();


            if($model->save(false)){
                return $this->redirect(['site/profile', 'id' => $model->ID]);
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create-departed', [
                'model' => $model,
                'anniversary' => $modelAnn]);

        }
    }

    return $this->render('create-anniversary', [
        'model' => $model,
        'anniversary' =>$modelAnn, 
    ]);
}
```

The quetion is that I want to use only one controller (which is actionCreate()) by all these 3 pages. It means i want to do if else for all these 3 pages(Page A,B and C).

Comment: Hi, provide some code and better describe the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the difference between pages? Why you use one action instaed of three actions? Why action name is `actionCreate` but view name is `index`?

Comment: The difference between these 3 pages is that there is some text field required in page A but not in Page B. So thats why I separate into different pages.

Comment: create different actions for every page dont use the if else inside the single action to display the pages and make it complex.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass some parameter to the action:

```
public function actionCreate($type = 'create')
{
    $typeToPageMapping = [
        'create' => 1,
        'departed' => 8,
        'anniversary' => 4,
    ]

    $model = new Memoriam(['scenario'=>'create']);
    if ($type == 'anniversary') {
        $modelAnn = new Anniversary();
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && ($type != 'anniversary' || $modelAnn->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))) {
        $model->picture1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'picture1');
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->picture1 = $this->savePicture($model);
            $model->page = $typeToPageMapping[$type];
            $model->save();
            if ($type == 'anniversary') {
                $modelAnn->decease_id = $model->ID;
                $modelAnn->save();
            }    
            if($model->save(false)){
                return $this->redirect(['site/profile', 'id' => $model->ID]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'type' => $type,
        'anniversary' => $modelAnn ?? null,
    ]);
}

protected function savePicture($model)
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if($model->picture1 == null) {
        return null;
    }

    $dir = "img/".$session['UserID']."/memoriam/";

    if(!file_exists($dir)) 
    {
        $old = umask(0);
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        umask($old);
    }
    $path = md5(date("YmdHis")) . '.' . $model->picture1->extension;
    $model->picture1->saveAs($dir.$path);
    return $path;
}
```